# JS regex to match all parts of the URL ignoring a specific path that consists of a dynamic value within that URL

Tags: regex

Example URL that the regex should match:

`https://domain/a/b/c/d/e/`i39m33rgp5jcrohl5atwe4c9`/g/h.file`

This shouldn't be matched: `i39m33rgp5jcrohl5atwe4c9`

I was thinking something along the lines of this, tests on https://regex101.com/ doesn't seem to match it properly though. Any pointers?

`^/a/([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)(\.file)?$`

Comment: Please give more examples and a clear explanation as to what parts should be matched.

Comment: Hi @WaisKamal so the parts that I code blocked should be matched except for that randomly generated ID in that specific position

Comment: So you want to explicitly match `https://domain/a/b/c/d/e` and `/g/h.file` that surround a piece of text?

Comment: Yep! Because that string is dynamically generated

Comment: Why not just separate the two with a pipe `|` (or) character and escape the special characters? `https://domain/a/b/c/d/e/i39m33rgp5jcrohl5atwe4c9/g/h.file".match(/https:\/\/domain\/a\/b\/c\/d\/e\/|\/g\/h\.file/g)`.

Comment: That could work, what if I want to just reference each path without assuming knowledge of the string? In this case, just the position

Comment: Probably something like this:
`(\/.\/.\/.\/.\/.\/)|(\/.\/.)(\.+)(file)`

Comment: The JavaScript tag should be removed as this has nothing to do with JS even if your use case it use this in JS.

Comment: @CodyE the JavaScript tag is relevant here. JavaScript regex syntax is different from Java regex syntax, which in itself is different from C++ regex syntax.

Comment: "*What if I want to just reference each path without assuming knowledge of the string?*" This is why I've asked if you want to ***explicitly*** match those characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
(^https?:\/\/(?:.*?\/){6}).*?\/(.*)$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/RR1rwk/2/)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
(               ##Starting 1st capturing group here.
  ^https?:\/\/  ##Checking condition if value starts from http/https://
  (?:.*?\/){6}  ##In a non-capturing group doing non-greedy match till / up to 6 times, just before dynamic value in URL.
)               ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
.*?\/           ##Again going non-greedy match till next occurrence of / here.
(.*)$           ##In 2nd capturing group having everything, rest of URL here.
```